# Visual Studio Code Espressif extension does not install ESP-IDF properly

Tags: visual-studio-code, espressif-idf

- Ubuntu 23.10
- Visual Studio Code v1.85.1

I did the following steps (based on the official [guide](https://github.com/espressif/vscode-esp-idf-extension/blob/master/docs/tutorial/install.md)):

1. installed the Espressif extension
2. installed the prerequisites: `sudo apt-get install git wget flex bison gperf python3 python3-pip python3-venv cmake ninja-build ccache libffi-dev libssl-dev dfu-util libusb-1.0-0`
3. installed the `master` branch from github ESP-IDF using the configuration page of the extension

It downloads and installs everything, but then there are errors:

```
/bin/sh: 1: riscv32-esp-elf-gcc: not found
Command failed: riscv32-esp-elf-gcc --version
/bin/sh: 1: riscv32-esp-elf-gcc: not found
Error checking riscv32-esp-elf version
Error: Command failed: riscv32-esp-elf-gcc --version
/bin/sh: 1: riscv32-esp-elf-gcc: not found

/bin/sh: 1: xtensa-esp-elf-gcc: not found
Command failed: xtensa-esp-elf-gcc --version
/bin/sh: 1: xtensa-esp-elf-gcc: not found
Error checking xtensa-esp-elf version
Error: Command failed: xtensa-esp-elf-gcc --version
/bin/sh: 1: xtensa-esp-elf-gcc: not found
```

I repeated the procedure on two different machines (with the same versions) and the results are the same.

Am I missing anything? Should not the installer take care of everything?